# How can I make a histogram for more than one column of a data frame?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe df, now I want to make a histogram using ggplot2 function I want to merge the data of two columns 1 and 2

+geom_histogram

So I tried:

```
v<-c(df$column1,df$column2)
myplot = ggplot(v)
myplot+geom_histogram()
```

I get an error:

> ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class numeric

Is there another way to merge columns?

My only problem is that I have yearly data and I just want to compare it without considering years. Phrased differently pour it all together.

Comment: I think you need to just wrap v in an ```aes```: ```myplot = ggplot(aes(v)) ```

Comment: now it says ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class uneval

Comment: try make v as a data frame, then plot

Comment: Your question is lacking a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
v<-c(df$columm1,df$columm2)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot()+aes(v)+geom_histogram(binwidth = (0.01))+xlim(c(-0.1,0.1))+labs(x="Jahresuberschuss",y="count")`
```